# Trying to stop timer from another class

Tags: android, timer

I'm using timer in my application and I'd like to stop it from another class. So I have an Activity and two classes: MainActivity,Timer,Pause.

MainActivity calls a method from Timer class to start the countdown. I have a button which calls a method from Pause class to stop the timer. It's seems like pretty easy but I always got NullPointerException error message.

MainActivity:

```
public TextView txt;
public TextView szamlalo;
Timer i;
Pause p;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello);
    szamlalo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.szam);
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    p = new Pause(szamlalo,txt,this);
    i = new Timer(szamlalo,this,txt);

    i.startTimerbig();

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            p.stopminden();
        }
    });
}
```

Timer class:

```
public Timer bigtimer;
public TimerTask bigtimerTask;
public final Handler bighandler = new Handler();

int ido = 10;
TextView szamlalo;
TextView txt;
Context context;
Over over;


public Timer(TextView szamlalo,Context context,TextView txt){
    this.szamlalo = szamlalo;
    this.context = context;
    this.txt = txt;
}


public void startTimerbig() {
    bigtimer = new Timer();
    biginitializeTimerTask();
    bigtimer.schedule(bigtimerTask, 3000, 1000);
}

public void bigstoptimertask(){
    bigtimer.cancel();
}

public void biginitializeTimerTask() {

    bigtimerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            bighandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    ido--;
                    szamlalo.setText("" + ido + "s");
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Pause class:

```
TextView szamlalo;
TextView txt;
Context context;
Timer i;

public Pause(TextView szamlalo,TextView txt,Context context){
    this.szamlalo = szamlalo;
    this.txt = txt;
    this.context = context;
    this.i = new Timer(szamlalo,context,txt);
 }

public void stopminden(){
    i.bigstoptimertask();
}
```

The error message also says that this line is the guilty one:

```
 bigtimer.cancel();
```

If anyone has an idea how to do that please response!

Comment: You should learn some basic .

Comment: Thanks now it works! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Pause(TextView szamlalo,TextView txt,Context context){
this.szamlalo = szamlalo;
this.txt = txt;
this.context = context;
this.i = new Timer(szamlalo,context,txt);//HERE!!
```

}

You create a new object of Timer in the last line, it's not the same object with field 'i' of class 'MainActivity' and it's field 'bigtimer' not inited because it's startTimerbig() never been called;